# Actions - separated objects

Tags: animation, nla-editor

I am lost in actions and NLA editor, even if I watched a lot of tutorials.
Is there possible to merge animations of more objects to the one action?
My character is a cartoon character and there is more independent parts. In case I wanna animate for example action "idle", I have to animate each part. If I run all these actions together, it works. Can I group them to one action? 
Still cannot find any complex tutorial of NLA editor and examples of the best practices for this part of blender.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but is there something wrong with grouping the parts together into one object?  You could use Vertex groups to make it easy to select the different parts of the character while animating.  This would go around the actions not being together.